# Python WSGI can't find local modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to get my Flask application to work with WSGI under Apache on RHEL 8. A flat file with no imports works fine, and the development server works fine, but WSGI returns module not found errors. This is my file strucuture:

```
/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp/
    utility/
        configuration.py
        logging.py
    __init__.py
```

Contents of `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request, abort
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse, inputs

from utility.configuration import Configuration
from utility.logger import Logger

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

configuration = Configuration()
logger = Logger()

class Main(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        return {'message': 'Hello World.'}


api.add_resource(Main, '/')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Running the Python test server works fine.

Accessing the server via WSGI on Apache gives the error:

```
File "/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  from utility.configuration import Configuration
No module named 'utility'
```

What do I need to do for WSGI to be able to see these modules?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `__init__.py` file to the `/utility/` directory for Python to treat the directory as a module.